# symplectic groups are always split?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $F$ be a number field or a non-archimedean local field of characteristic $0$ or $p$ or archimedean field.

Let $G$ be a symplectic group defined over $F$.

I am wondering whether $G$ is always split. If it is not, it depends on the field $F$?